# How do I create a custom icon for on iPad that's basically just a URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ipad

Let me be more specific

If you go to maps.google.com with your ipad, it'll ask you to "add the app" to the home screen. When you do, it will create a browser URL link to the home screen.. along with a custom google map icon.

How is this achieved? I'm assuming a javascript/jquery can achieve this..?

PS: Sorry if this sounds so noob-ish.. im not big on apple developement

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is add this to the `<head>` of your page:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/icon.png" />
```

Then create an image for your icon. I think it works best with icons that are 57x57.

iOS will automatically add rounded corners and a shine so keep that in mind when designing the icon.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a particular icon for each device use the following

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="touch-icon-iphone.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="touch-icon-ipad.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="touch-icon-iphone4.png" />
```

Check out the apple docs more customization options
http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html